# How/where to get the source jar of datastax-cassandra-connector-2.3.0 version?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to cassandra ,trying to connect cassandra using spark with spark-cassandra-connector 2.3.0 jar ...while i am trying to saveToCassandra it is giving an error pointing to localhost instead of cassandra cluster. I am using scalaIDE , while debugging it expecting a source jar of spark-cassandra-connector 2.3.0 , i dont find it on maven , where to download the source jar of the same?

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources (such  books/tutorials, tools/libraries) are off-topic here.

Comment: @GhostCat, sir i am NOT asking books/tutorials , solution i am asking ...

Comment: You ask for a link pointing to some other site. That is the essence of "off site resource". Questions that result in answers that boil down to links, are off topic here. Sorry, I didn't make that rule.

Comment: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.3.0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the url where you get the sources
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.3.0/

Comment: @user3252097 sir I dont find the catalyst source jar in below http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-catalyst_2.11/2.3.1 where should i download it from ? please help me

Comment: Sir now i got it ,...not sure what was the problem here....thank you   http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-catalyst_2.11/2.3.1/